# How to set different Model fields for Grid and for Form when using CRUD::setModel()?

Tags: atk4

In Agile Toolkit framework, when I add a CRUD object, can I specify which fields are visible during Grid mode and which fields are visible during Edit mode?

I am using "setModel()" to populate fields. E.g.

```
$crud = $this->add("CRUD");
$crud->setModel("Foo");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRUD == Grid + Form

So you want to show one bunch of Model fields in Grid and another in Form.

```
$cr = $this->add('CRUD');
$cr->setModel('YourModel',
    array('name','username','email','password'), <-- Form fields
    array('name','email','password')             <-- Grid fields
);
```

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/View/CRUD.php#L218